# Is it possible to use Visual Studio on macOS?

Tags: visual-studio, macos

I want to install Visual Studio on macOS. Is this possible?

Comment: Emulation will work. Also this seems more appropriate for the superuser stackexchange.

Comment: if you have www.dreamspark.com account, then you can download 
Windows Virtual PC 2007 on your Mac freely! Using this software, you can install and run Windows Server 2012. You can download Windows Server also using dreamspark.com. After these steps are completed, you can install Visual Studio Community freely to your Virtual Windows Server OS. Hope this helps!

Comment: #want. although, if I had VS on OSX, I would have no reason to use Windows... but don't tell Microsoft ;-)

Comment: You can now with Visual Studio Code! https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

Comment: the times they are a-changin http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/29/microsoft-shocks-the-world-with-visual-studio-code-a-free-code-editor-for-os-x-linux-and-windows/#.hnbsi2:H8rY

Comment: As of today there is a version of Visual Studio for Mac OS X called Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: That's the dream. VisualStudio for OSX. Don't know why Microsoft doesn't want to make this application as i'm sure that many would buy it for MAC.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac has just been announced:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790182.aspx

Comment: vs for mac cached page version still available: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Vk2On-9psscJ:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790182.aspx+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: 2016-11-17 Visual Studio full for Mac, released: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt790182 by Mikayla Hutchinson @mjhutchinson

Comment: No answer has been accepted yet (May 2017 as I write).  The question was originally asked in 2011, probably about a then-current version of Mac OS X (or whatever it was called at the time, but not macOS).  I wonder if we should rewrite the question such that someone with an old Mac would benefit from it.  I presume the 2017 Visual Studio for Mac will not run on a 2011 Mac.

Comment: More about my earlier comment.  It seems Mac VS 2017 supports Sierra or El Capitan only.  Refer https://www.visualstudio.com/en-au/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-mac.  So I wonder if we should edit the question such that it reflects what the asker wanted at the time.  Or do we change it to make it more useful for the average reader for now and in future?  Or leave it alone?

Answer (score 67):

Yes! You can use the new Visual Studio for Mac, which Microsoft launched in November.

Read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt790182

Download a preview version here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Visual Studio is not the same as Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: yeah, they're not quite the same, VS for Mac is closer to Xamarin Studio. But it is what Microsoft has released as the VS experience for mac :)

Comment: It's worth noting the new .NET Core is cross-platform, as is the 'Visual Studio Code' editor, which also now supports debugging.

Thus, if you install Visual Studio Code and .NET Core on a Mac in OS X you can quite freely edit and compile and run and debug and share your code with Visual Studio 2017 on a PC.

Comment: @JoshVarty Does Visual Studio for Mac include the IDE only, or also the MSVC compiler?

Comment: @Patrick As far as I understand it VS for Mac currently supports C#, F# and JS/TS. So I don't think that you can use it to develop C or C++ applications on Mac.

Answer (score 46):

I recently purchased a MacBook Air (mid-2011 model) and was really happy to find that Apple officially supports Windows 7. If you purchase Windows 7 (I got DSP), you can use the Boot Camp assistant in OSX to designate part of your hard drive to Windows. Then you can install and run Windows 7 natively as if it were as Windows notebook.

I use Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 on my MacBook Air (I kept OSX as well) and I could not be happier. Heck, the initial start-up of the program only takes 3 seconds thanks to the SSD.

As others have mentions, you can run it on OSX using Parallels, etc. but I prefer to run it natively.

Comment: Very helpful. As others already stated, there is no Visual Studio for Mac OS. Virtualization and dual boot (Windows) can be used instead. I prefer dual boot (Windows). So Visual Basic can just be installed same as on PCs. As dualboot is locked on my company device I tried VirtualBox with Windows7 image and Visual Basic Express (Windows Mobile dev.) but performance was slow (Macbook Pro, 2.4 GHz, Intel Core i5, no SSD).

Comment: The down side is just that the fonts in Windows look awful compared to OSX.

Answer (score 23):

I guess you can install it via Parallel or in any other Virtual machine with windows in it

Comment: That's not really running it on Mac OS X.

Comment: A virtual machine or dual-boot between Windows and OS X is the best way to go. I have an old CoreDuo MacBook Pro that I used to use for my primary development, and I recommend [Oracle VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for virtualization, since it's free. If you're doing hardcore development though, you will really want to dual-boot. Either way, you're going to have to pay for a Windows license.

Comment: You can use VS (IDE) through Parallels for Server-Side programming and VS Code (Editor) on Mac for Client-Side.

Comment: At the moment, the question starts "I want to install Visual Studio on macOS."  Does running it in Parallels count?  Should the question be re-worded to say whether a VM solution would be acceptable?

Answer (score 16):

No. Neither Visual Studio or the .NET framework will run on Mac OSX (although the latter is changing). However, if you want to write an application in a similar framework, you could use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) and [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

Comment: Ok now when .NET is available opensource on Linux and Mac you should fix your comment "will not run" :)

Comment: Actually, .NET Core can now run on Mac (and Linux as well).

Comment: But not .NET Framework guys.... So this comment still holds true, neither VS Community nor .NET Framework can run on OS X.

Answer (score 6):

There is no native version of Visual Studio for Mac OS X.

Almost all versions of Visual Studio have a [Garbage rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) on Wine's application database, so Wine isn't an option either, sadly.

Comment: Visual Studio 6 and visual studio 2005 express edition have gold ratings on Wine's application database.

Comment: Completely true at the time, but Microsoft now releases Visual Studio for both Mac and Linux.

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Answer (score 4):

While Parallels is technically a VM it is capable of running games in high resolution at a high frame rate. If you run Parallels in Coherence mode it completely integrates Windows 7 into  OS X and .Net framework is fully supported. So yes you can install Visual Studio on your Mac however the Apps you created would only run of windows computers unless they were web based.

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio on Mac OSX, not on Mac hardware

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! There's a Visual Studio for macs and there's Visual Studio Code if you only need a text editor like Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

Current Visual Studio versions (2019, 2022) are targeted specifically for Mac as well.

I found [Microsoft’s Visual Studio for Mac getting complete overhaul with native UI and more](https://9to5mac.com/2021/04/19/microsofts-visual-studio-for-mac-overhaul/) pretty enligthing

This question is outdated.